# SPARQL Query that retrieves individuals of a subclass that owned by another individual of a class in Protégé?

Tags: sparql, rdf, ontology, protege, object-property

I started using Protégé as required by my job and currently learning how to use SPARQL Query for it.

I got a question in my mind as following:

Let's say that I have an ontology as this:

```
owl:think
      Fruit
          - Apples
          - Bananas
     -Owner
```

Now, I have an individual for the subclass "Apples" and let's name it "GreenApple". Also for the subclass "Bananas" and called "SweetyBanana".

I have many individuals for the class "Owner", but let's name one of them through a data property "hasName" as "Jimmy".

The individual which hasName of "Jimmy" has a relationship through an object property called "hasFruit" and it links him to the "GreenApple" and to the "SweetyBanana" individuals as following:

```
{ Individual (which is named "Jimmy" by the hasName property) hasFruit GreenApple }.
{ Individual (which is named "Jimmy" by the hasName property) hasFruit SweetyBanana }.
```

Now my question is that if I want to do SPARQL Query that retrieves the Fruits that owned by the individual "Jimmy" and belong to the "Apples" subclass. What would be the right structure of such query. I tried many but non is working perfectly.

I tried this but no hope:

```
?ID :hasName "Jimmy"^^xsd:string .
?ID rdf:subClassOf :Fruit .
?ID rdf:subClassOf ?FruitList  .
?FruitList :hasFruit ?JimmyFruit .
```

Also tried this, but no hope too:

```
?ID :hasName "Jimmy"^^xsd:string .
?ID rdf:subClassOf :Apples .
?ID rdf:subClassOf ?AppleFruit  .
?AppleFruit :hasFruit ?JimmyFruit .
```

So simply that I just want the query to show me the fruit that owned by Jimmy which is under the subclass of Apples. I don't want to see the Bananas individuals, nor that fruits which are owned by other owners.

Remmber:
hasName is a Data Proprty.
hasFriut is an Object Property.
Apples is a subclass of the class Fruit.
Bananas is a subclass of the class Fruit.
Owner is a class .
"Jimmy" is a value.
GreenApple is an individual that in the Apples subclass.
SweetyBanana is an individual that in the Bananas subclass.

Comment: Can you provide a couple of examples of the SPARQL queries you tried and the results obtained?

Comment: `````?ID :hasName "Jimmy"^^xsd:string .
?ID rdf:subClassOf :Fruit .
?ID rdf:subClassOf ?FruitList  .
?FruitList :hasFruit ?JimmyFruit .  ````

Comment: `?ID rdf:subClassOf :Fruit .` would mean Jimmy is a subclass of `Fruit` - I doubt this is the case, right? Why not `SELECT * WHERE {?ID :hasName "Jimmy"^^xsd:string .

?ID :hasFruit ?JimmyFruit . }` - note, you don't have a FruitList in your data model, thus, it doesn't make sense to query for such. SPARQL does match exactly the data resp. graph you have.

Comment: The issue is that I want that fruits which belong to the subclass "Apples", so GreenApple, however, your query gives me all fruits including SweetyBanana. This is why I also tried using rdf:subClassOf :Apples to classify my outcomes to be all in the range of Apples, but couldnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need something like:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
?id :hasName "Jimmy" ;
    :hasFruit ?fruit .
?fruit rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* :Apples }
```

Now, it doesn't matter if `:Apples` is a subclass of `:Fruit`, as you are only interested in apples anyway.

In response to your comment, we can use a property path:

```
?fruit rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* :Apples
```

means that `?fruit` is either an instance of `:Apples`, or an instance of a (direct or indirect) subclass of `:Apples`.

Comment: So how if the Apples subclass is has/under other sub classes like this: Fruit > Apples > App1, App2, App3 and the App2 hasFruit GreenApple1(individual) / the App3 hasFruit GreenApple2(individual). And I want to retrive all the apples under the Apples subclass. Yours works if I just name the subclass that directly holds the wanted individuals. So like this SELECT *
WHERE {
?id :hasName "Jimmy" ;
    :hasFruit ?fruit .
?fruit rdf:type :App2 } and it jsut gives me GreenApple1. But if I put Apples instead of App2, I get nothing.

Comment: I added to my answer to deal with this. Basically, you can use a property path to travel up the hierarchy until you get to `:Apples`.

Comment: `:Apples` cannot have subpaths, only subclasses. Using `rdfs:subClassOf*`, what we are doing is retrieving all the direct AND *indirect* subclasses of `:Apples`.
Try it and see if we are missing out any apples.